# Stopping the GUI after running the codes in the Toga python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface

This is my code and I have used Toga and instagrapi libraries

```
from instagrapi import Client


# toga
import toga
import toga.widgets
from toga.app import BackgroundTask,App
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW

# other
import pickle,time


green = '#2da15f'
red = '#a12d2d'
blue = '#2d48a1'  

class IGbot(App):
    def startup(self): #this is your Ui application
        self.login_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))
        self.getuser_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))
        self.filter_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))
        self.start_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))
        container = toga.OptionContainer(
            content=[
                ("login", self.login_box,toga.Icon('./resources/icons/instagram.png')), 
                ("getuser", self.getuser_box,toga.Icon('./resources/icons/user.png')), 
                ("filter", self.filter_box,toga.Icon('./resources/icons/filter.png')), 
                ("start", self.start_box,toga.Icon('./resources/icons/start.png')) 
            ]
        )
        #--------------------------------------------------------------
        # set login page
        #--------------------------------------------------------------
        self.cl = Client()
        self.cl.delay_range = [1,5]
        
        self.username = toga.TextInput(placeholder='username')
        self.password = toga.PasswordInput(placeholder='password')
        self.verify_code = toga.TextInput(placeholder='verify_code')
        self.btn_login = toga.Button(text="Login",on_press=self.login)
        self.login_via_session = toga.Switch(text="login via session")
        self.login_result = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN,text_align="center",flex=1))
        scroll_login_result = toga.ScrollContainer(content=self.login_result,horizontal=False,style=Pack(flex=1))
        
        self.login_box.add(
            self.username,
            self.password,
            self.verify_code,
            self.btn_login,
            self.login_via_session,
            scroll_login_result
            ) 
        
        
                    
        
        #--------------------------------------------------------------
        # set get user page
        #--------------------------------------------------------------
        
        self.getuser_result = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN,text_align="center",flex=1))
        scroll_getuser_result = toga.ScrollContainer(content=self.getuser_result,horizontal=False,style=Pack(flex=1))
        
        self.table_posts = toga.Table(
            headings=['id', 'url'],
            on_activate=self.remove_selected_post,
            style=Pack(flex=0)
        )
        
        self.input_post = toga.TextInput(placeholder='Enter your Url post')
        handler_post_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=ROW))
        handler_post_box.add(
            toga.Button("Add post",on_press=self.addpost),
            toga.Button("Clear all post",on_press=self.clearposts),
            toga.Button("Get users from all posts",on_press=self.get_users),
            toga.Label('double click on post for delete')
        )
        
        self.table_users = toga.Table(
            headings=['id', 'username','is_private'],
            style=Pack(flex=0)       
        )
        
        self.getuser_box.add(
            self.input_post,
            handler_post_box,
            self.table_posts,
            self.table_users,
            scroll_getuser_result
        )
        
        #--------------------------------------------------------------
        # set filter user page
        #--------------------------------------------------------------
        self.filter_from_following = toga.Switch(text='filter users by your followings',value=False)
        self.table_filtered_users = toga.Table(
            headings=['id', 'username','is_private'],
            style=Pack(flex=0)       
        )
        self.filteruser_result = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN,text_align="center",flex=1))
        scroll_filteruser_result = toga.ScrollContainer(content=self.filteruser_result,horizontal=False,style=Pack(flex=1))
        self.filter_box.add(
            toga.Button('filter users',on_press=self.filterusers),
            self.filter_from_following,
            self.table_filtered_users,
            scroll_filteruser_result
        )
        
        #--------------------------------------------------------------
        # set start page
        #--------------------------------------------------------------
        self.start_result = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN,text_align="center",flex=1))
        scroll_start_result = toga.ScrollContainer(content=self.start_result,horizontal=False,style=Pack(flex=1))
        self.switch_following = toga.Switch('follow users',value=False)
        self.message = toga.TextInput(placeholder="enter your message for send to directs")
        self.message.style = Pack(direction=ROW,text_align="center")
        self.switch_send_direct = toga.Switch('send direct to users',value=False)
        self.switch_like = toga.Switch('like users',value=False)
        
        self.start_box.add(
            toga.Button('start page',on_press=self.start),
            self.message,
            self.switch_following,
            self.switch_send_direct,
            self.switch_like,
            scroll_start_result
        )
        
        ##########################################################
        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = container
        self.main_window.show()
        self.beep()
        
        
    async def login(self,widget):
        if self.login_via_session.value:
            try:
                self.cl = Client()
                self.cl.delay_range = [1,5]
                self.cl.load_settings("session.json")
                self.cl.login (self.username.value, self.password.value)
                self.cl.get_timeline_feed()
                self.login_result.add(toga.Label("login via session complete",style=Pack(color=green)))
            except Exception as e:
                self.login_result.add(toga.Label(f"Error to login via session : {e}",style=Pack(color=red)))
        elif self.login_via_session.value == False:
            self.login_result.add(toga.Label(f"plaease wait ... login via username and password",style=Pack(color=blue)))
            self.cl = Client()
            self.cl.delay_range = [1,5]
            try:    
                await self.cl.login(self.username.value,self.password.value,verification_code=self.verify_code.value)
                self.login_result.add(toga.Label("login via username and password complete",style=Pack(color=green)))
                self.cl.dump_settings("session.json")
                self.login_result.add(toga.Label("new session dumped",style=Pack(color=green)))
            except Exception as e:
                self.login_result.add(toga.Label(f"Error login via username and password : {e}",style=Pack(color=red)))   
    async def addpost(self,app):
        try:
            id = self.table_posts.data.__len__()
            self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"{id} seted",style=Pack(color=green)))
            self.table_posts.data.append((id + 1,self.input_post.value))
            self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"data added",style=Pack(color=green)))
            self.input_post.value = ""
        except Exception as e:
            self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"Error to add post : {e}",style=Pack(color=red)))
    async def clearposts(self,app):
        try:
            self.table_posts.data.clear()
            self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"cleared all posts",style=Pack(color=green)))
        except Exception as e:
            self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"Error ro clear posts : {e}",style=Pack(color=red))) 
    async def remove_selected_post(self,app,row):
        try:
            if self.table_posts.selection:
                selected_row = self.table_posts.selection
                self.table_posts.data.remove(selected_row)
                self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"your selected post deleted",style=Pack(color=green)))
        except Exception as e:
            self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"can't delete your selected post : {e}",style=Pack(color=red)))
    async def get_users(self,app):
        posts = []
        for post in self.table_posts.data:
            posts.append(post.url)
        users = []
        for post in posts:
            try:
                pk = self.cl.media_pk_from_url(post)
                post_id = self.cl.media_id(pk)
                likers = self.cl.media_likers(post_id)
                self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"from {post_id} likers geted",style=Pack(color=green)))
            except Exception as e:
                self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"Error cant get likers : {e}",style=Pack(color=red)))
            for liker in likers:
                try:
                    if liker not in users:
                        users.append(liker)
                        self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"{liker.username} added",style=Pack(color=green)))
                except Exception as e:  
                    self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"cant get user : {e}",style=Pack(color=red)))  
        self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"all users added : {len(users)}"))
        try:
            with open("users.pkl", "wb") as f: 
                pickle.dump(users, f)
                self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"users.pkl saved",style=Pack(color=green)))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error to save pickle:{e}")
            self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"Error to save pickle: {e}",style=Pack(color=red)))
        for user in users:
            self.table_users.data.append((user.pk,user.username,user.is_private))
        self.getuser_result.add(toga.Label(f"users added to table"))
    async def filterusers(self,app):
        try:  
            with open("./users.pkl", "rb") as f:
                users = pickle.load(f)
                self.filteruser_result.add(toga.Label(f"users loaded from pickle",style=Pack(color=green)))
        except Exception as e:
            self.filteruser_result.add(toga.Label(f"Error to load pickle : {e}",style=Pack(color=red)))
        dicts = {}
        for item in users:
            id = item.pk
            dicts[id] = item
        users = dicts
        if self.filter_from_following.value:
            try:
                followings = self.cl.user_following(self.cl.user_id_from_username(self.username.value))
                self.filteruser_result.add(toga.Label(f"followings getted",style=Pack(color=green)))
            except Exception as e:
                self.filteruser_result.add(toga.Label(f"Error cant get followings: {e}",style=Pack(color=red)))
        for user in users.copy():
            try:
                if users[user].is_private:
                    users.pop(user)
                    self.filteruser_result.add(toga.Label(f"deleted {user} from users",style=Pack(color=green)))
                if self.filter_from_following.value: 
                    if user in followings:
                        users.pop(user)
                        self.filteruser_result.add(toga.Label(f"deleted {user} from users",style=Pack(color=green)))
            except Exception as e: 
                self.filteruser_result.add(toga.Label(f"Error to delete user: {e}",style=Pack(color=red)))              
        users = list(users.values())
        try:
            with open("users.pkl", "wb") as f: 
                pickle.dump(users, f) 
                self.filteruser_result.add(toga.Label(f"users.pkl saved!",style=Pack(color=green)))
        except Exception as e:
            self.filteruser_result.add(toga.Label(f"Error to save pickle : {e}",style=Pack(color=red)))    
        self.filteruser_result.add(toga.Label(f"all {len(users)} users saved"))
        for user in users:
            self.table_filtered_users.data.append((user.pk,user.username,user.is_private))
        self.filteruser_result.add(toga.Label(f"all users added to filtered table"))
    async def start(self,app):
        pass

       
        
    
    
def main():
    return IGbot('IGbot','org.com.IGbot')
```

For example, when I use the login button, its method is executed
But the problem is that the GUI stops along with it and this is not good at all
And I don't want this to happen, and according to Toga's own documentation, I used asynchronous programming, but it didn't help, what should I do?